# Already login How to override user session + devise + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I am using Devise for authentication. I am already login to site.After login creating *user* and *company*. How can I destroy current session and create a new session for newly created user.

Please look at the code.

----> sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

----> routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
          sessions: 'users/sessions'
        }
  root to: "companies#index"

  resources :companies do
  end
  resources :company_users do
  end

end
```

----> companies_controller

```
def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here I am creating my user and company. After completion of this I want create session for this newly created user.

Any suggestion are welcome as well please give specific answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you be more elaborate you want to reset the session or impersonate user..??

Comment: I have found my solution. As I have written I want to close current user session and create a new session for new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i guess, your company has many users. If you want to login the recent created company's first user, you can do some thing like

`reset_session
 sign_in @company.users.first`

after your company is created.

The reset_session is a rails method which would delete the current session and the `sign_in object` is a devise method you can use to login as any user.

This should help.